# Can Calling Dispose() more than one time on an object lead to a crash?

Tags: c#, winforms, crash

I am investigating a sporadic crash in my app and still not sure what is causing it. It happens sometimes when I want to close my MDI form that contains an VB 6.0 or maybe VC 6.0 Text control - its wrapper for C# as Interop.  While looking at the code I noticed I have some code like this:

```
 private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing) //Disposing of everything: managed and unmanaged resources.
            {
                moTextEditor.Dispose();  --here
                moTextEditor.Dispose();  --here
            }

            // Deal with our own & whatever other unmanaged resources (this used to be done in the finalizer, above)
            SetLockedFields(false);

            disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

so noticedthat *moTextEditor.Dispose();* line getting repeated two times?  What do you think? Can this be the issue?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to test your theory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [IDisposable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) documentation for [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) specifically states:

> If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times. Instance methods other than Dispose can throw an ObjectDisposedException when resources are already disposed.

If the object implements `IDisposable` *properly* this should not be an issue.

That being said, not all implementations of `IDisposable` follow the rules.  I personally would say that object has a bug and should be corrected if calling `Dispose` multiple times is problematic.

Answer (score 2):

The repeated dispose looks like a mistake, but normally that shouldn't cause any problems.

If implemented correctly, an object can be disposed more than once without harm.

Answer (score 2):

> Can Calling Dispose() more than one time on an object lead to a crash?

Yes.

> Does Calling Dispose() more than one time on an object always lead to a crash?

No.

Basically, it depends entirely on the implementation.  The fact that an object implements `IDisposable` simply means that it has a `Dispose` method.  There are many guidelines about how you should implement it, but there are virtually no absolute rules.

So now we ask:

> Is it considered a good practice to ensure that multiple calls to `Dispose` for my `IDisposable` object don't throw exceptions, cause crashes, or otherwise break stuff?

Yes.

> Does everyone actually follow that guideline?

No.

> Is that actually my problem here?

*shrug *  It's hard to say.  We don't know how that object specifically implements `Dispose`.

Comment: It *should* never lead to a crash, though.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yep, I got there towards the end.

Answer (score 1):

BDotA,

Generally it wouldn't make your application to crash, but you need to consider what the Dispose() method of moTextEditor is doing.